# What is the inheritance error in this code?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I am studying old exam questions for Java and I can't figure out this one:

One of the declared classes does not compile...

1. What will you change in order to compile the classes?
2. What will be the output, assuming you have fixed the compilation errors correctly? Briefly explain your answer.

I think it would be class C and I guess it is because it is not applying proper OOP principles but could someone help me explain it better?

```
public interface A {

  public void doSomeProcess(String s);

}

public class AImpl implements A {

  public void doSomeProcess(String s) { 
         System.out.println("A Imple Code"); [. . .] }
}

public class B {
       public A doIt() { [. . .] }

       public String execute() { [. . .] }
}

public class C extends B {

       public AImpl doIt() { [. . .] } 

       public Object execute() { [. . .] }
}
```

Comment: Why not try to compile the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `B#execute()` return type is `String` whereas `C#execute()` method has return type `Object`. When Overriding `B#execute()` you come only return a subtype of `String` but not anything more generic.

Think about it, since `C` is subclass of `B`, it can be substituted for `B` any time. But if `C#execute()` can return say `Date` or `Integer` or `Object` then this substitution cannot happen. Therefore, you can return subtypes but not supertypes in case of overridden methods.

On the other hand parameters of overridden methods can be supertypes of their parent class method parameters. They cannot be subtypes.

Eg
A method  in parent class `public Map doThis(List n)` , when overriden has to handle something which is at least a `List` (say `Collection`) and can return something which is at most a `Map` (say `HashMap`)
So this can be overridden my this method `public HashMap doThis(Object k)` as it has to handle atleast a `List` and return a Map